# A rare use of "have to"?

Tags: grammar

Ran into this:
*I do hope that all the workers of our society will one day have to their lawful and rightful rights.*

Is the use of *have to* correct?

I normally would say "I do hope that all the workers of our society will one day reach/get their lawful and rightful rights."

Comment: "Have" would work, but I cannot find any way the "to" fits in there. You might want to reconsider lawful and rightful rights. Apart from the right/rights alliteration, the rights they have are already lawful, even if the law gives them few rights...

Comment: What's the source of the quote, Juya?  It looks like it was not written professionally or possibly translated from another language because in addition to the missing word, the "rightful rights" is also clumsily written.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I think you are right, the text is not flawless. http://www.rezapahlavi.org/details_article.php?article=642&page=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is an extra word, or possibly a missing word. "Have to their lawful rights" doesn't make any sense. "Have their lawful rights" makes sense. The writer could also have meant something like "have to *use* their lawful rights". What is currently written seems like an error.

Your suggestions "reach" or "get" would work, but colloquially I would choose "receive", or if they are fighting hard for these rights (instead of just receiving them), "achieve" or "attain".

Additionally, "rightful rights" is very redundant. That phrase means "the rights to which they have a right". I would just leave it as "lawful rights".

Comment: And what would give them those rights, if not the law? Are there 'unlawful rights', or is lawful rights as redundant as 'rightful rights'?

Comment: @oerkelens "Lawful rights" isn't necessarily redundant. "Human rights", for example, are (in some people's opinion) things that every human on Earth has a right to, even if they live in a country that does not recognize those rights. Additionally, the sentence could be referring to a situation where people have certain rights by law, but in reality are not allowed to practice them. They have the rights "on paper", but in practice, they are oppressed or restricted.

Comment: Sure, there are rights like human rights, but then you would ask for the law to include those rights if human rights are not lawful yet. The "you have the rights only on paper"-interpretation is possible, but i somehow cannot get that feeling from the OP's sentence...

Comment: @oerkelens We need more context to know what the sentence means. It could be that we're hoping for the day when "the law recognizes workers' rights" or when "the company stops infringing on the workers' lawful rights" or any of a number of other things.

Comment: My only point is that "lawful rights" is not *necessarily* redundant - it depends on the context - but "rightful rights" is always redundant.

Comment: context: http://www.rezapahlavi.org/details_article.php?article=642&page=1

Comment: Good answer, but I'd say that "have to USE" would be grammatically correct, but wouldn't make sense in this context. If you "have to use your rights", that implies that someone is trying to oppress you. I wouldn't HOPE that someone is being oppressed and so "have to use" his rights. I can't think of a word that would fit after "have to" and actually make sense in context, but maybe I'm just not being imaginative enough.

Comment: I agree that this sounds like it was poorly translated from another language. "Rightful rights" sounds lame, but something like "rightful legal privileges" or "the rights to which they are due" sound perfectly reasonable and mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: Reading the line in context, I think the missing word could be **access**. One day they will have **access** to their rights.

Comment: @oerkelens: Re the supposed "redundancy" of *lawful rights.* Firstly, obviously redundancy is a *feature* of English, on average usually used *to advantage* - it's not just some weed in our richly-stocked gardens of eloquence, to be vilified and extirpated on sight. And in the specific case of *lawful **rights***, [over 100,000 written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22their+lawful+rights%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) suggest that native speakers (writers?!) feel that either emphasis or particularisation justify explicitly identifying those rights as entitlements *under law*